# Retrieving a Single File and the Behavior of Directory.GetFiles C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file-io

```
public int RunStageData(string rootDirectory, stringdataFolder)
{
    string[] files = new string[] { };
    files = Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectory + dataFolder);
    string[] tableOrder = new string[] { };
    tableOrder = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\_projects\ExampleProject\src", "TableOrder.txt");
    System.IO.StreamReader tableOrderReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(tableOrder[0]);

    for (int count = 0; count < files.Length; count++)
                    {
                        string currentTableName =tableOrderReader.ReadLine();
                        //files[count] = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\_projects\ExampleProject\src", currentTableName);
                    }

}
```

Hi everyone, sorry if my code is a bit sloppy. I'm having an issue primarily with the line I have commented out.  So basically what I'm trying to do here is to populate a string array of file names based on the ordering of these names in a txt file. So I read the first line from the txt file, then retrieve the name of that file in the directory(assuming it exists) and put it in the first spot of the array, then move on.

For Example if the txt file had these words in the following order:

1. Dog
2. Sheep
3. Cat

I would want the array to have Dog first, then Sheep, then Cat.  My issue is that the line that I have commented gives me an error that says "Error 41  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'"

---

I'm guessing the reason for this is that Directory.GetFiles has the possibility of returning multiple files.  So, is there another method I could use to achieve the results I'm looking for?  Thank you.

Comment: Why are you creating useless `new string[] { }`s?

Comment: the error tells you why you are getting the error you cannot convert a string[] array into a `string` you are better off reading the file into a Generic<T> object of string `List<string>` and sorting from there..

Comment: Well yeah looking at it I don't know why tableOrder is a string array, but I don't know if I see how that is related to my question.

Comment: Normally, if the method name is a plural, the return is some kind of array

Comment: `tableOrder` is a string array because [`GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) returns an array of names even when only one file matches the pattern. It's the same for your second call.

Comment: here is a good site on `GetFiles` has awesome examples you can definitely learn from [GetFiles Method](http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/)

Comment: Thanks for everyones help and resources, I got it figured out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question:

> So basically what I'm trying to do here is to populate a string array
>   of file names based on the ordering of these names in a txt file. So I
>   read the first line from the txt file, then retrieve the name of that
>   file in the directory(assuming it exists) and put it in the first spot
>   of the array, then move on.

So, your TableOrder.txt already contains the files in the correct order, thus you can do:

```
string[] files = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\_projects\ExampleProject\src\TableOrder.txt")
```

Comment: Ah, this one was so obvious I guess its just been a long day haha thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want the contents of the file (if you just want the file name and need to check for existance a different solution will be required).

```
files[count] = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(@"C:\_projects\ExampleProject\src", currentTableName));
```

And a couple other suggestions:

- Don't initialize your variables with bogus data, `= new string[] {}` can be removed
- Don't use `count` as an indexer, it is confusing (count is a property of the array after all)
- Use `Path.Combine` when joining paths. It is much easier as it handles the `\` for you.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but I am actually just looking for the name. Thanks for the other tips though!

Answer (score 0):

If your array files contains only paths, you can do it as:

```
path = @"C:\_projects\ExampleProject\src\" + currentTableName;
If(File.Exists(path))
{
files[count] = path;
}
```